# Slope in Android view

Tags: android, android-view

In my android view I want to have a slope. The screen should have in the first third of the screen a picture in the background. And the two-thirds should be white. The border between the image and the white section should have this slope...

[image]

Comment: You simply need a custom drawable and a transparent (or non existing) toolbar. Good luck!

Comment: Use image(drawable) which have trapezium shape.

Comment: Would anyone be kind enough to quote an example for above?

Comment: After lot of searching, hopefully helps someone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066413/slanting-or-sloping-ui-design-in-android