# I want to make a layout like this below in the image given:The blue color trapezium at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android

I want to make a layout like this below in the image given. The blue color trapezium at the bottom of the screen

[image]

Comment: what have you tried? Nobody is going to write code for you here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066413/slanting-or-sloping-ui-design-in-android